# Uncaught TypeError: {function} is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick. How can I fix this error?

Tags: javascript, html, function

This is probably a stupid question for who already knows everything about JavaScript and HTML.
I've been doing an [incremental game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_game) but when I create the save function the console just keeps calling this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: save is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:26)
```

My project is using the [break_infinity.js](https://github.com/Patashu/break_infinity.js) library, where the game can store numbers bigger than 1.79e308 (64-bit numbers).

Here's my HTML code:

```
<head>
    <script src="break_infinity.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="+1.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Idle Exponential</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;" onunload="save()">
    <div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Number')" id="default">Number</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'IP')">Infinity Points</button>
    </div>
    <p id="number" class="number">Number: 1.00 (x1.01/s)</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="Number" class="tabcontent">
    <button onclick="IncreaseMultiplier1()" class="Upgrade" id="Upgrade1">Increase Multiplier per second. <br> Increases IP gain by a fraction. <br> <br> Cost: 100 <br> Level: 0</button>
    </div>
    <div id="IP" class="tabcontent">
    <b id="IPamount" class="IPamount">You have 2 Infinity Points</b>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="IncreaseIP1()" class="Upgrade" id="Upgrade2">Increase IP multiplier per tick. <br> Cost: 1.00e50 (number)<br> Level: 0</button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="save()" class="Upgrade">Save game!</button>
    <button onclick="load()" class="Upgrade">Load game!</button>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("default").click();
    </script>
</body>
```

And here's my JavaScript code:

```
// Main game values.
var save = {
    number: new Decimal(1),
    multiplier1: new Decimal(1.05),
    multiplier2: new Decimal(0.00000000000001),
    IP: new Decimal(1),
    OldIP: new Decimal(1),
    MultiplierEffect1: new Decimal(1),
    Upgrade1Cost: new Decimal(100),
    Upgrade1Level: new Decimal(0),
    BaseEffect1: new Decimal(0.001),
    CostEffect1: new Decimal(2),
    IPmultiplier: new Decimal(1),
    Upgrade2Cost: new Decimal(1e50),
    Upgrade2Level: new Decimal(0),
    CostEffect2: new Decimal(50),
    BaseEffect3: new Decimal(1.4),
    BaseEffect4: new Decimal(2.5),
}

// Multiplies the number every tick.
function multiply() {
    save.number = Decimal.times(save.number, save.multiplier1);
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "Number: " + notate(save.number) + " (x" + notate3((save.multiplier1.pow(40))) + "/s)";
}

save.multiplier1 = Decimal.add(save.multiplier1, 1);

// Multiplies the multiplier1 value, which that variable multiplies the main number value.
function upgrade1() {
    save.multiplier1 = Decimal.divide(save.MultiplierEffect1, 1.49).times(save.multiplier1.log(2)).add(1.00003);
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = `Number: ${notate(save.number)}`  + " (x" + notate3((Decimal.pow(save.multiplier1, 40))) + "/s)";
    document.getElementById('IPamount').innerHTML = "You have " + notate(save.OldIP) + " Infinity Points (x" + notate3(Decimal.pow(save.IPmultiplier, 2)) + "/s)";
}

// Click to earn more Infinity Points.
function EarnIP() {
    save.IP = Decimal.times(save.IP, save.IPmultiplier);
    save.OldIP = save.IP;
    save.MultiplierEffect1 = Decimal.pow(save.OldIP, save.BaseEffect1);
    save.multiplier2 = Decimal.times(0.00003, save.MultiplierEffect1);
    document.getElementById('IPamount').innerHTML = "You have " + notate(save.OldIP) + " Infinity Points (x" + notate3(Decimal.pow(save.IPmultiplier, 2)) + "/s)";
}

function IncreaseMultiplier1() {
    if (save.number.mantissa >= save.Upgrade1Cost.mantissa && save.number.exponent >= save.Upgrade1Cost.exponent) {
        save.BaseEffect3 = Decimal.times(save.BaseEffect3, 0.7);
        save.BaseEffect4 = Decimal.add(save.BaseEffect3, 1.1);
        save.BaseEffect1 = Decimal.times(save.BaseEffect1, save.BaseEffect4);
        save.IPmultiplier = Decimal.times(save.IPmultiplier, 1.005);
        save.CostEffect1 = Decimal.times(save.CostEffect1, 1.4142135623730950488016887242097);
        save.Upgrade1Cost = Decimal.pow(10, Math.round(save.CostEffect1));
        save.Upgrade1Level = Decimal.add(save.Upgrade1Level, 1);
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "Number: " + notate(save.number) + " (x" + notate3((save.multiplier1.pow(40))) + "/s)";
        document.getElementById('Upgrade1').innerHTML = "Increase Multiplier per second.<br>Increases IP gain by a fraction. <br> <br> Cost: " + notate(save.Upgrade1Cost) + "<br> Level: " + save.Upgrade1Level;
    };
};

function IncreaseIP1() {
    if (save.number.mantissa >= save.Upgrade2Cost.mantissa && save.number.exponent >= save.Upgrade2Cost.exponent) {
        save.IPmultiplier = Decimal.times(save.IPmultiplier, 1.01);
        save.CostEffect2 = Decimal.times(save.CostEffect2, 2.2360679774997896964091736687313);
        save.Upgrade2Cost = Decimal.pow(10, Math.round(save.CostEffect2));
        save.Upgrade2Level = Decimal.add(save.Upgrade2Level, 1);
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "Number: " + notate(save.number) + " (x" + notate3((save.multiplier1.pow(40))) + "/s)";
        document.getElementById('Upgrade2').innerHTML = "Increase IP multiplier per tick. <br> Cost: " + notate(save.Upgrade2Cost) + " (Number) <br> Level: " + notate4(save.Upgrade2Level);
    };
};
        
    
// This notates both values in HTML.    
function notate(n) {
    var m = n.mantissa;
    var e = n.exponent;
    if (e < 5) return (m * Math.pow(10, e)).toFixed(0);
    return `${m.toPrecision(3)}e${e.toLocaleString("pt-BR")}`;
};

function notate2(n) {
    var m = n.mantissa;
    var e = n.exponent;
    if (e < 4) return (m * Math.pow(10, e)).toPrecision(3);
    return `${m.toPrecision(2)}e${e.toLocaleString("pt-BR")}`;
}

function notate3(n) {
    var m = n.mantissa;
    var e = n.exponent;
    if (e < 3) return (m * Math.pow(10, e)).toPrecision(4);
    return `${m.toPrecision(3)}e${e.toLocaleString("pt-BR")}`;
}

function notate4(n) {
    var m = n.mantissa;
    var e = n.exponent;
    if (e < 3) return (m * Math.pow(10, e)).toPrecision(3);
    return `${m.toPrecision(3)}e${e.toLocaleString("pt-BR")}`;
}
// Automation at the start of the game!

var mainGameLoop = window.setInterval(function () {
    multiply()
}, 25);

var mainGameLoop = window.setInterval(function () {
    upgrade1()
}, 25);

var mainGameLoop = window.setInterval(function () {
    EarnIP()
}, 500);

var mainGameLoop = window.setInterval(function () {
    load()
}, 1);

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function save() {
    localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
};

function load() {
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(save));
};
```

I hope somebody can help me!

Comment: you call `save()` but that is an object, not a function

Comment: You used save for object and function change the either function name or object name you define first at top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object named "save" and a function also with the same name.
So just change the function name in the definition in .js file as well as in call in .html file

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `save` as both a function and an object; apparently, the latter definition won.